# How to transform HTML entities in string into HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am passing to a javascript function this string:

```
<div>Peter</div><div>Paul</div><div>Jane</div>
```

and when I print this code out in javascript, the output is this:

```
<div>Peter</div><div>Paul</div><div>Jane</div>
```

But I would need to transform it into this:

```
Peter
Paul
Jane
```

to execute the HTML code.

How to do that in javascript/jQuery?

Thank you

Comment: Will the string always be a "list" of DIV elements?

Comment: How are you "printing" it? Post a complete code example please.

Comment: I can adjust it, so there can be always DIVs

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using DOM manipulation instead of RegEx.

We create a "sandbox" element first and insert our HTML string. By inserting it using innerHTML, the string transforms into DOM objects.

```
var str = '<div>Peter</div><div>Paul</div><div>Jane</div>';
var sandbox = document.createElement('div');
sandbox.innerHTML = str;
```

And now get the string contents from the DOM objects:

```
var items = [].slice.call(sandbox.children).map(function(el) {
  return el.textContent;
});

//=> ["Peter", "Paul", "Jane"]
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this array of strings. Example:

```
items.join('\n');
// "Peter
// Paul
// Jane"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the tags

`string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");`

Answer (score 0):

First off, the question seems slightly misleading, because your html string DOES print out the three names stacked on top of each to the browser:

```
Peter
Paul
Jane
```

Because behind the scenes all you have is three names contained in three divs stacked on top of each other.

```
<div>Peter</div>
<div>Paul</div>
<div>Jane</div>
```

Also, it seemed a little like you were asking "how can I convert this HTML string to HTML?" So what I am assuming you are *really asking*, is how to strip the html tags from the html string, and print the names on top of each other without HTML?

**You can try these variations on the same idea:**

```
// Replace div tags with Empty Spaces
var htmlString2 = "<div>Peter</div><div>Paul</div><div>Jane</div>";
var noHtmlString = htmlString2.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," ");
//  Peter  Paul  Jane

// Split values into an array, then process them however you want
var htmlString3 = "<div>Peter</div><div>Paul</div><div>Jane</div>";
var array = htmlString3.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," ").split(" ");
// ["", "Peter", "", "Paul", "", "Jane", ""] 

// Turn your closing div tags into line breaks (remove opening tags)
var htmlString4 = "<div>Peter</div><div>Paul</div><div>Jane</div>";
var lineBreaks = htmlString4.replace(/<div>/ig, "").replace(/<\/div>/ig, "\n");
/*

Peter
Paul
Jane

*/
```

The last option on that list is one way to force a non-html string to print line breaks, what it does, is replace `<div>` tags with an empty space, and closing div tags `</div>` with a linebreak character `\n`, that would create this this string:

```
   Peter
   Paul
   Jane
```

But those line break characters are only rendered in settings that recognize them, so you could modify the script to replace the closing tags with anything that will force a line break to get the formatting you want. Also, my regular expressions in that example only support div tags, you would have to build a more robust regular expression if you want to support more html tags.

Lastly, you may have noticed that some of these solutions above leave empty spaces before or between the text values. That is something to consider when building out your processing choices.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for?

**[Here is the jsfiddle I used to test this answer.](http://jsfiddle.net/ah666hk5/)**

Hope this helps!